# Which ASP.NET Control should I use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, listbox, repeater

I am unsure which asp.net control to use.  I've tried / thought about with no avail.

```
Repeater / ListBox (doesn't allow for multiple lines)
Repeater / Div (No click unless I use JavaScript postback)
```

I have a list of Messages in codebehind that I would like to attach to some UI control that could display them (spanning multiple lines per item), with good styling.

I need the clickable functionality of a selected item change in a ListBox.  But I need the ability to space out each Line item to span multiple lines and possibly contain graphics.

***A good visual example would be the inbox view of Microsoft Outlook. Each message consists of the Email-Address, timestamp, etc spaced out and styled nicely.  How do I accomplish this with asp.net? :)***

Comment: Some options: repeater (prob easiest) or something like [knockout.js](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail).

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Please see my respond to TGH post below.  What would go inside the repeater that could hold multiple small pieces of independent infomration (properties from my current List's Message Object)?

Comment: Depending on how you make the repeater or nested repeater, yes you could make it one big clickable item.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Can you show me an example of that somewhere?

Comment: assuming your document is HTML5, you can just put your container `div` that holds all the small pieces of information inside an anchor tag. Without seeing your datasource or visually what you are trying to accomplish, its hard to show an example.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev  The datasource is a List<Message> assume it has all the standard properties, message, Username, sent on, the visuals are easy, if you can imagine what your outlook inbox looks like.  I'm not sure an anchor tags accomplishes what i'm trying to do.. I'm not trying to link to anywhere, but instead get into a codebehind method to load the full conversation between the logged in user and the person that sent the message that is selected from the List<Message>

Comment: Wrap the stuff in your repeater with an anchor. If you run into problems, you'll need to open a new question with some code and what issues you have... or hope that someone comes across who wants to write code from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a repeater inside another repeater...
That will help you nest multiple elements per row

I typically use KnockoutJS for these types of requirements though since it offers great data bound templates

Comment: The biggest problem with a repeater is that it doesn't address the Clickability requirement, the item inside the repeater has to be ENTIRELY clickable containing multiple small pieces of information on different lines. How does that worK?

Comment: It depends. Do you need the click events to be server side or client side? You can attach click behavior in JQuery for client side, or using the repeater binding events to attach sever side events

Comment: I need to get to a C# codebehind method.  I will need to parse information from the item that sent it and load the rest of the messages from that user. But they have to click anywhere inside that box.  The repeater isn't enough. How does the repeater Binding events help when an item inside the repeater is clicked? Which item should be inside the repeater?